# How to trigger a function when there is a value change in subscribed store in Svelte?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component, svelte-store

One of my components is subscribed to a variable in a store. Whenever there is a change in that store var, I want to trigger a function.

stores.js

```svelte
    import { writable } from "svelte/store"; 
    export const comparedProducts = writable([1,2,3]);
```

Component.svelte

```svelte
    import { comparedProducts } from "../stores.js";
    
    //if there is a change in $comparedProducts trigger this function eg. ([1,2])
    const someFunction = () => {
      //do something
    }
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Found a cleaner solution

```svelte
import { comparedProducts } from "../stores.js";
$: $comparedProducts, run();

function run(){
  //do something here
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this would deserve a downvote. I think it's clean & in the spirit of Svelte..

Comment: Actually, when the value of the store is falsy, this will not work. You'll need a comma instead of a logical AND: `$: $comparedProducts, run();` This will make sure the `run` function is always executed, regardless the value of the store.

Answer (score 7):

in componenet.svelte

```svelte
    import { comparedProducts } from "../stores.js";
    
    //if there is a change in $comparedProducts trigger this function eg. ([1,2])
    const someFunction = () = >{
      // do something
    }
    
    // stores can be subscribed to using .subscribe()
    // each new value will trigger the callback supplied to .subscribe()
    
    let unsubscribeStore = comparedProducts.subscribe((currentValue) => {
        //currentValue == $comparedProducts
        someFunction()
    })

    // call unsubscribeStore() after finishing to stop listening for new values
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @rohanharikr's answer

```js
$: $comparedProducts, (() => {
  // do something here
})();
```

You can make an anonymous function which will automatically create and unsubscribe to the function.

Answer (score 0):

More detail and working [Repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/ddac71a2b6244705a3d0b73bab9d6039?version=3.42.6) demoing a counter.

store.js

```
import { writable } from "svelte/store"; 
export const count = writable(0);
```

Component.svelte

```
import { count } from "../store.js";
$: if($count > 0) { foo($count) }

    
function foo($count) {
   console.log($count)
}
```